# Bipartite Graph and Non-connected node?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Is this one bipartite graph or not?

[image]

It is a simple question for you but i can't find the answer.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a graph to be bipartite?

Comment: If i put vertex in the 2 disjoint set it is bipartite i think.

Comment: @Zafer But you can always divide vertices into two disjoint sets regardless of whether the graph is bipartite.  There's more about the properties of the two sets that you haven't expressed.

Comment: @ErickWong I want to express. How can i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the top-left vertex was adjacent to all three of the right-side vertices, you would have $K_{3, 3}$, a bipartite graph. The nodes on the left form one partition, and the nodes on the right form another partition. Note that no nodes in a single partition are adjacent. So removing the three edges from the top-left vertex of $K_{3, 3}$ leaves you with your current graph.

So the graph you have is still bipartite, as you have:

-Two sets of vertices

-No pair of vertices in a given partition (set) are adjacent

**Edit:** Regarding your question on the maximum number of edges a bipartite graph on $n$ vertices can have without being connected. So we have one vertex disconnected. If $n$ is odd, then we have $K_{(n-1)/2, (n-1)/2}$. Otherwise, we have $K_{(n-1)/2, (n-1)/2 + 1}$. Then just count up the edges.

Comment: I have a question about getting disconnected bipartite graph with maximum edge. And I think if it is bipartite, it isthe answer.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "disconnected bipartite graph with maximum edge?"

Comment: Updated my post. Just an FYI- it's probably good to ask your questions upfront, rather than tacking them on as comments afterwards. :-)